# Construct a Mobius map that maps the strip $\{z\in \mathbb C:0<\Im (z)<1\}$ onto the area between the circles $|z-1|=1$ and $|z-2|=2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Construct a Mobius map that maps the strip $\{z\in \mathbb C:0<\Im
>  (z)<1\}$ onto the area between the circles $|z-1|=1$ and $|z-2|=2$.

(The question earlier asked for a map from $|z-1|<1$ onto $|z|>2$ for which is got $g(z)=\frac 2{z-1}$ but I can't really see how to use this)

I can't get anywhere useful, I just have pages of algebra getting me nowhere.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Start from the other end. What is the image of the region between those two circles under the map $z\mapsto 1/z$?

Comment: The hint above from @DanielFischer says it all, but to understand the target region, you really want to open it up by a map such as his. Don’t forget: a pair of parallel lines in the plane becomes a pair of circles tangent at a single point $P$ under any transformation that sends $\infty$ to $P$.

Comment: @DanielFischer  
Thanks so far but I'm embarrassed to say I still can't do it. I don't know how to find the image of the region, so I found the image of the two circles and hoped the region between them would be mapped to the region between their images but it appears this isn't true. Using what you suggested I was able to find the map $g(z)=\frac{4i}{z+i} which I believe does map the circles to the lines but substituting in values between these lines does not give something between the circles. Unfortunately I must ask for help again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it's easier to move a pair of parallel lines to a desired destination than doing it for a pair of nested circles touching at one point. Therefore I suggest first constructing the map in the other direction, and then inverting the resulting Möbius transformation to obtain the map in the required direction.

One transforms a pair of nested circles touching at $p$ into a pair of parallel lines by applying a Möbius transformation that maps $p$ to $\infty$. Here, the two circles touch at $0$, and the simplest Möbius transformation mapping $0$ to $\infty$ is $\rho \colon z \mapsto 1/z$. $\rho$ maps $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ to itself, and the two circles intersect the real axis at right angles, so the image of each of the two circles under $\rho$ is a straight line intersecting $\mathbb{R}$ at a right angle, i.e. a line of the form $\{ w : \operatorname{Re} w = c\}$.

The smaller circle intersects $\mathbb{R}$ at $0$ and at $2$, and $\rho(2) = \frac{1}{2}$, so the image of $\{ z : \lvert z-1\rvert = 1\}$ under $\rho$ is $\bigl\{ w : \operatorname{re} w = \frac{1}{2}\bigr\}$. The larger circle intersects $\mathbb{R}$ at $0$ and at $4$, so the image of $\{ z : \lvert z-2\rvert = 2\}$ is $\bigl\{ w : \operatorname{Re} w = \frac{1}{4}\bigr\}$.

The point $3$ lies between the two circles ($\lvert 3-1\rvert > 1$ and $\lvert 3-2\rvert < 2$), and $\frac{1}{4} < \rho(3) = \frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{2}$, so the region between the two circles is mapped to the strip $\bigl\{ w : \frac{1}{4} < \operatorname{Re} w < \frac{1}{2}\bigr\}$.

We now have a vertical strip of width $\frac{1}{4}$, and we want a horizontal strip of width $1$, thus we need a scaling by a factor of $4$, and a rotation by $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then we need a translation to move the strip to the required position. All that is easily achieved by

$$\sigma \colon w \mapsto i(4w-1),$$

and hence a Möbius transformation doing the ultimate goal is $(\sigma\circ \rho)^{-1}$. All other such transformations are obtained by composing it with an automorphism of the strip.

To find $(\sigma\circ \rho)^{-1}$, we isolate $z$ in

$$w = i\biggl(\frac{4}{z} - 1\biggr),$$

yielding

$$z = \frac{4}{1-iw} = \frac{4i}{w+i} =: g(w).$$

So you did get the (well, **a**, it's not unique) right map, and you just have miscalculated when trying to verify.

Let's make a couple of checks. The image of the line $\{w : \operatorname{Im} w = 0\}$ under $g$ is the circle through $g(\infty) = 0$, $g(0) = 4$, and $g(1) = \frac{4}{1-i} = \frac{4(1+i)}{2} = 2(1+i)$. It is easily seen that this is the circle $\{ z : \lvert z-2\rvert = 2\}$.

The image of the line $\{ w : \operatorname{Im} w = 1\}$ is the circle through $g(\infty) = 0$, $g(i) = \frac{4}{1-i^2} = 2$, and $g(2+i) = \frac{4}{1 - i(2+i)} = \frac{4}{2(1-i)} = 1+i$, which is $\{ z : \lvert z-1\rvert = 1\}$.

A point between the two lines is $\frac{i}{3}$, and $g(i/3) = \frac{4}{1-i^2/3} = \frac{4}{4/3} = 3$ lies between the two circles. Hence $g$ maps the strip $\{ w : 0 < \operatorname{Im} w < 1\}$ to the region between the two circles, as desired.

Comment: Super, thanks a lot